# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy eventhough Controller has Crossorigin enabled and Header set

Tags: java, angular, typescript, hibernate, mariadb

I am trying to post data to a MariaDB, by passing it through my service into the controller and then into the repository. However, when trying to make a `http.post` to the controller URL, I get the response:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/car/create' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
While I've found this error has been described alot of times, the proposed solutions seems to have not worked for me yet, as I both enabled everything in the `http-header` aswell as enable `@Crossorigin` in my controller.

Here are the important parts of my code:

Service

```
  readonly httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN": "http://localhost:4200",
      "ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS": "true"
    })
  };

  public save(car: Car) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/car/create', car, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/car")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@Transactional
public class CarController {

    @Autowired
    public CarController(CarRepository carRepository) {

        this.carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/create")
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public void addCars(@RequestBody final car car) {
        this.carRepository.save(car);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my last such application, I only added `@CrossOrigin` to the respective controllers in the java backend, without further configurations and options. Try it!

Comment: @SwissCodeMen just tried it, same error response

Comment: What if you place `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` above `@Controller`?

Comment: @kellermat tried it with and without http-header set, both results in still the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure if that's an optimal solution, but it is a solution.

I added this slice of code, to basically tell the CORS-Config directly to allow CrossOrigin and it seems to have worked:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        System.out.println("CORS Config success");
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200"); // "/create-cars"
            }
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows + R and then try running the below command in RUN on windows.

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

try localhost:4200 in the newly opened chrome.

Hope it helps!
Happy coding